Are overlapping MPI_Ibcast safe if the root or datatype differs?
I can't seem to find information on how non-blocking bcast calls are distiguished by mpi. I was wondering if the below situations are always safe:
1.
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL);

  vector<int> buf1(1'000'000);
  vector<int> buf2(1'000'000);
  vector<MPI_Request> reqs(2, MPI_REQUEST_NULL);

  MPI_Ibcast(buf1.data(), buf1.size(), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
  MPI_Ibcast(buf2.data(), buf2.size(), MPI_INT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);

  MPI_Waitall(reqs.size(), reqs.data(), MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

I.e. having overlapping non-blocking bcasts where the root differs each time, and the bcasts are called in the same order on all processes.
2.
#include <cstdint>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL);

  vector<int64_t> buf1(1'000'000);
  vector<double> buf2(1'000'000);
  vector<MPI_Request> reqs(2, MPI_REQUEST_NULL);

  MPI_Ibcast(buf1.data(), buf1.size(), MPI_INT64_T, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
  MPI_Ibcast(buf2.data(), buf2.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);

  MPI_Waitall(reqs.size(), reqs.data(), MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

I.e. the root is the same but the datatype differs whilst having the same sizes. Again the bcasts are called in the same order on both processes.
If these are safe can we go even further and have the same broadcast signatures except for the buffers used?

Neither data type nor root argument are significant for matching collective communication. Not even the kind of collective is significant. The only thing that matters is the order of the calls. (Of cause you need to guarantee that all these arguments are consistent across all participating ranks). All this is defined in the introduction of the non-blocking collective communication section of the mpi standard. Other than with point to point communication, you cannot mix blocking and non-blocking collective calls across ranks.
